# How do I detect whether sys.stdout is attached to terminal or not?

Tags: python, console, terminal

Is there a way to detect whether `sys.stdout` is attached to a console terminal or not? For example, I want to be able to detect if foo.py is run via:

```
$ python foo.py  # user types this on console
```

OR

```
$ python foo.py > output.txt # redirection
$ python foo.py | grep ....  # pipe
```

The reason I ask this question is that I want to make sure that my progressbar display happens only in the former case (real console).

Answer (score 291, accepted):

This can be detected using [`isatty`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.isatty):

```
if sys.stdout.isatty():
    # You're running in a real terminal
else:
    # You're being piped or redirected
```

To demonstrate this in a shell:

- `python -c "import sys; print(sys.stdout.isatty())"` should write True
- `python -c "import sys; print(sys.stdout.isatty())" | cat` should write False

Comment: It gets weird when you are in a terminal but doing redirections stderr could be going to a terminal while stdout not.

Comment: @arhuaco - that's where `sys.stderr.isatty()` comes in -- or even `sys.stdin.isatty()` for that matter.