# Handling pagers with python's subprocess

Tags: python

I'm writing some scripts that call git commands, but having trouble when git tries to output using a pager, which blocks on user input. For example the following drops me in `less` (afaik) and I have to `q` to continue:

```
subprocess.Popen(['git', 'diff', '--stat', '--cached', 'origin/master']).wait()
```

In this specific case I can disable that by telling git not to use a pager:

```
subprocess.Popen(['git', '--no-pager', 'diff', '--stat', '--cached', 'origin/master']).wait()
```

Is there some general solution (*Edit:* i.e. that works for everything, not just `git`), where I can capture the output and not block on the pager, or is there some mechanism that could be informing the sub-process (git in this case) not to use a pager automatically?

I've tried closing subprocess's stdin and experimenting with the `shell=True/False` argument, but neither helped.

---

*Update:*
For example,
`git diff --stat --cached origin/master` will land you in a pager if the output is longer than a page. `git diff --stat --cached origin/master | cat` will not. How does git know? How can I apply this same effect using subprocess?

Comment: '--no-pager' should not use 'less'. Are you using an up-to-date version of git ? Your git command works fine for me on 2.9.0 (without less)

Comment: @MauriceMeyer Yes, it does work for git. However I'm after a general solution for any programs that may attempt to automatically use a pager.

Answer (score 2):

`git` is sensible to the `PAGER` environment variable, the following works nice:

```
subprocess.Popen(['git', 'diff', '--stat', '--cached', 'origin/master'], env={'PAGER':'cat'}).wait()
```

Comment: Thanks! However I'm also after a solution to the root cause rather than just fixing git in the case.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to pipe escape sequences required to exit the pager you expect to be opened. You can use the `stdin` argument to `subprocess.Popen()` to create a pipe, where you can send escape characters when you expect this issue to arise:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(
        ['git', 'diff', '--stat', '--cached', 'origin/master'], 
        stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

p.stdin.write('q') # q should quit most pagers
p.wait()
```

This could be easily wrapped up in functions or classes to handle different pagers in a simple way. It doesn't handle all of them as-is, but simply changing what is being written to the pipe allows others to be handled.

Answer (score 0):

Two changes seem to fix this:

1. Provide an `stdout` and `stderr` pipe.

   ```
   subprocess.Popen(['git', '--no-pager', 'diff', '--stat', '--cached', 'origin/master'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE).wait()
   ```

   However, after making this change *DO NOT USE WAIT*:

   > Warning This will deadlock when using stdout=PIPE and/or stderr=PIPE and the child process generates enough output to a pipe such that it blocks waiting for the OS pipe buffer to accept more data. Use communicate() to avoid that.[<sup>from the docs</sup>](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait)

   Instead...
2. Use `communicate()`:

   ```
   p = subprocess.Popen(['git', '--no-pager', 'diff', '--stat', '--cached', 'origin/master'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
   stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
   print p.returncode
   ```

   (can also use `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` to merge stderr with stdout)

I guess `git` is doing something like the following to decide whether to use a pager or not:
[How do I detect whether sys.stdout is attached to terminal or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077113/how-do-i-detect-whether-sys-stdout-is-attached-to-terminal-or-not)