# CLI spinner vs. Log file flooding - how to solve this dilemma?

Tags: logging, continuous-integration, command-line-interface

I have a small helper tool with a CLI that facilitates the notarization process for macos Catalina. It is both run manually in the terminal for ad-hoc notarization, but also in the CI chain. As the notarization process involves a waiting time that can be anywhere between 5s and 15h, it would be nice to:

- Display on the CLI that the process is still active (some spinner/progress bar)
- Don't flood the CI logs with every single step the spinner/progress bar iterates through
- Keep the CI process alive by having some output every x minutes (keep alive ping)

This seems to be a universal problem for all tools used both in CLI and CI context. Now some tools go for parameters like `--nospinner` or `--buildserver`, others go for environment variables like `BUILDSERVER=1`. A third option might be to strip spinners from the logfiles, similar to masking passwords, before saving.

What are the advantages/disadvantages of each approach, and how could this be solved in a better way?

Answer (score 0):

I learned from [How do I detect whether sys.stdout is attached to terminal or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077113/how-do-i-detect-whether-sys-stdout-is-attached-to-terminal-or-not) that you can detect in what context your output will be shown, and thus you can adjust the update interval accordingly before running spinner/progress bar.