# How to check if stdout is attached to a terminal, in Rust?

Tags: terminal, rust, stdout

Essentially this question, but for Rust:
[How do I detect whether sys.stdout is attached to terminal or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077113/how-do-i-detect-whether-sys-stdout-is-attached-to-terminal-or-not)

I didn't see anything in the Stdout docs (https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Stdout.html)

Comment: Ah yes, I didn't find it because it's asking the inverse question. Pretty disappointing that it requires either FFI or a third-party crate, but if that's still the case then this does answer my question.

Comment: I mean, there's no cross platform notion of what a TTY is, so putting it in `std` would likely have adverse effects on portability.