# How does one make logging color in Django/Google App Engine?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, logging, colors

If one iswriting a Django/ Google App Engine application and would like to have logs that are conveniently conspicuous based on color (i.e. errors in red), how does one set that up?

I've copied the helpful solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384076/how-can-i-make-the-python-logging-output-to-be-colored), but I'm not sure how to integrate it into Django/Google App Engine.

I figured one would put the following in the application's main.py (i.e. essentially from the example here: [Running Django on Google App Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/django.html)):

```
from contrib.utils import ColouredLogger # from the SO question above
logging.setLoggerClass(ColouredLogger)
```

... where contrib.utils is where I put airmind's code from the above link to his SO answer.

However, that doesn't seem to do anything to the output to the console for GAE, which continues to be in the original format + plain color.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

We use [colorlog](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorlog) and it does exactly what you expect.

For posterity, the formatter config we use is:

```
'color': {
    '()': 'colorlog.ColoredFormatter',
    'format': '%(log_color)s%(levelname)-8s %(message)s',
    'log_colors': {
        'DEBUG':    'bold_black',
        'INFO':     'white',
        'WARNING':  'yellow',
        'ERROR':    'red',
        'CRITICAL': 'bold_red',
    },
}
```

Comment: Note that [colorlog](https://github.com/borntyping/python-colorlog) module does not support [256 colours](https://github.com/borntyping/python-colorlog/issues/7).

Comment: A link, to official docs about logging will be helpful as well. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/#examples

Answer (score 10):

Django already has support for color output through the '[DJANGO_COLORS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#syntax-coloring)' environment variable used for example when running the built in development server. Some person has noticed this and created a plug-and-play solution https://github.com/tiliv/django-colors-formatter; with that package on the project's python path my logging `settings.py` is as follow:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            '()': 'djangocolors_formatter.DjangoColorsFormatter', # colored output
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(name)s %(asctime)s %(module)s %(process)d %(thread)d %(pathname)s@%(lineno)s: %(message)s'
        },
        'simple': {
            '()': 'djangocolors_formatter.DjangoColorsFormatter', # colored output
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(name)s %(filename)s@%(lineno)s: %(message)s'
        },
    },
     # omitting the handler 'level' setting so that all messages are passed and we do level filtering in 'loggers'
    'handlers': {
        'null': {
            'class':'django.utils.log.NullHandler',
        },
        'console':{
            'class':'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'simple',
        },
        'mail_admins': {
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler',
            'formatter': 'verbose'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        '': { 
            'handlers': ['mail_admins', 'console'],
            'level': 'WARNING',
        },
    }
}
```

Sample console logging output using django-colors-formatter:
[image: Sample console logging output]

Comment: Install via `pip install git+https://github.com/tiliv/django-colors-formatter.git`

Comment: This package seems abandoned. It hasn't received any attention in 5 years. Try using `coloredlogs` instead. It's a generic python package that works really well with Django.

Answer (score 9):

Although this is not quite what the OP wanted (each line coloured by level), I wanted to share a nice alternative for log output colouring called [`rich`](https://rich.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) - a fantastic library for various rich text stuff to display in the terminal, authored by [@will-mcgugan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/673463).

#### Simple example

Activating `rich` colouring for Django logs is easy: use [`rich.logging.RichHandler`](https://rich.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/logging.html#rich.logging.RichHandler) instead of `logging.StreamHandler`, e.g.

```
# project/settings.py

...

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'rich.logging.RichHandler',  # <-- this
        },
    },
    'root': {
        'handlers': ['console'],
        'level': 'INFO',
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': os.getenv('DJANGO_LOG_LEVEL', 'INFO'),
            'propagate': False,
        },
    },
}
```

(this is the modified example from [Django logging docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/logging/#examples)). This will produce terminal logs like these:

[image: django-rich-logs]

#### Changing output format

Format customizations are done as usual by passing the handler arguments. E.g. to turn on [rich tracebacks](https://rich.readthedocs.io/en/stable/logging.html#handle-exceptions) and hide the timestamp column:

```
LOGGING = {
    ...
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'rich.logging.RichHandler',
            'rich_tracebacks': True,
            'show_time': False,
        },
    },
}
```

will yield

[image]

#### Changing output colours

Changing the colouring is possible, but not via logging config, as multiple colours and styles are applied to each line; you must provide a customized theme. An example that changes colouring of `INFO` label from the default blue to bold magenta:

```
import rich
import rich.theme

my_theme = rich.theme.Theme({
    'logging.level.info': 'bold magenta',
})
rich.reconfigure(theme=my_theme)

LOGGING = {
    ...  # no changes here
}
```

For more details, see [Styles](https://rich.readthedocs.io/en/stable/style.html) documentation. To inspect available theme keys and default values, issue

```
$ python -m rich.theme
```

and look for keys prefixed with `log.` or `logging.`.

#### Outro

Note that `rich` is so much more than just coloured logging; go check it out:

```
$ python -m pip install rich
$ python -m rich
```

Specifically for the logging use case, check out the output of

```
$ python -m rich.logging
```

to see more rendering examples than in the screenshots.

Answer (score 5):

I also wanted color output for the dev_appserver. I found the solutions here a little OTT (all I wanted was to make my logging.error() calls stand out. I ended up monkeypatching the logging module by dropping this in my main.py as a quick solution:

```
# monkey patch logger to dump ERRORs in red
import os
if os.environ['SERVER_SOFTWARE'].find('Development') >= 0:
    import logging
    old_error = logging.error
    def red_error(msg,*args,**kwargs):
        old_error("\033[22;31m%s\033[0;0m" % msg, *args, **kwargs)
    logging.error = red_error
```

This will only for on ANSI-color terminals.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a sample formater:

```
class Formatter(logging.Formatter) :
    _level_colors  = {
      "DEBUG": "\033[22;32m", "INFO": "\033[01;34m",
      "WARNING": "\033[22;35m", "ERROR": "\033[22;31m",
      "CRITICAL": "\033[01;31m"
     };    

    def format(self, record):
        if(Formatter._level_colors.has_key(record.levelname)):
            record.levelname = "%s%s\033[0;0m" % \
                            (Formatter._level_colors[record.levelname],
                             record.levelname)
        record.name = "\033[37m\033[1m%s\033[0;0m" % record.name
        return logging.Formatter.format(self, record)
```

You need to configure it, for example:

```
...
[formatters]
keys=console_formatter
...
[handler_console_handler]
class=StreamHandler
formatter=console_formatter
args=(sys.stdout,)
```

Comment: Why is `\033` needed?

Answer (score 3):

I used the [`coloredlogs`](https://pypi.org/project/coloredlogs/) package. Unlike `DJANGO_COLORS`, it's not specific to Django commands, and unlike `django-colors-formatter`, it's actively maintained.

I added a single line to my logging config, and now I get configurable coloured logs.

```
logging.config.dictConfig({
    ...
    'formatters': {
        'console': {
            # This line right here:
            "()": "coloredlogs.ColoredFormatter",
            'format': '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s [%(name)s:%(lineno)s] %(message)s',
        },
    },
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

The reset codes mentioned in the answer you linked to will work on a console in the local development server (but will likely take some tweaking - you'll have to chain it with the existing App Engine logging handler), but won't work in production, since in production log entries are output to an HTML page in your admin console.

You can, however, filter by log level in the admin console.

Comment: Thanks for answering, Nick. It's the chaining part that I'm having trouble with. :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe that you should create a logger subclass just for this - airmind's answer is fine as far as creating a specialised `Formatter` and specifying its use on a `StreamHandler`. But there's no need for a logger subclass. In fact airmind's use of a logger class adds a handler to every logger created, which is not what you want.

The solution airmind gave only works for terminals which support ANSI escape sequences - are you sure that your console does support them?

Comment: Thanks Vinay. Yes, my terminal supports ANSI colors.

Answer (score 1):

Install [colorlog](https://github.com/borntyping/python-colorlog)

(don't forget to put colorlog in **INSTALLED_APPS**)

create 'colored' in your **formatter**

```
 'colored': {
        '()': 'colorlog.ColoredFormatter',
        'format': "%(log_color)s %(levelname)-8s %(asctime)s %(module)s %(reset)s %(blue)s%(message)s",
    }
```

full example of logger in settings.py

```
LOGGING = {
'version': 1,
'disable_existing_loggers': False,
'formatters': {
    'colored': {
        '()': 'colorlog.ColoredFormatter',
        'format': "%(log_color)s %(levelname)-8s %(asctime)s %(module)s %(reset)s %(blue)s%(message)s",
    }
},
'handlers': {
    'console': {
        'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        'formatter': 'colored'
    },
},
'root': {
    'handlers': ['console'],
    'level': 'WARNING',
},
'loggers': {
    'django': {
        'handlers': ['console'],
        'level': os.getenv('DJANGO_LOG_LEVEL', 'INFO'),
        'propagate': False,
     },
  },
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution for Django with colorlog. It just colors simple django messages as they are. You only need to put it in your `settings.py`.

```
pip install colorlog
```

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'special': {
            '()': 'colorlog.ColoredFormatter',
            'format': '%(log_color)s[%(asctime)s] %(message)s'
        }
    },
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_true': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugTrue',
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'filters': ['require_debug_true'],
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'special'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'propagate': True,
        }
    }
}
```

[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z72df.png)