# Python logger - Different log format per level

Tags: python, logging

I want to have different formats per log level, i.e.:

logformat_info = "info ..."

logformat_warning = "warning ..."

My code so far (The logger is in a function because I pass it around between files):

```
def log(level='info'):
"""
    My logger function.
    :param level:
    :return:
"""
    log_colors = {
        "DEBUG": "white",
        "INFO": "green",
        "WARNING": "yellow",
        "ERROR": "red",
        "CRITICAL": "bold_red",
    }

    if level == 'info':
        LOG_LEVEL = logging.INFO
    elif level == 'debug':
        LOG_LEVEL = logging.DEBUG
    LOGFORMAT = "%(log_color)s%(log_color)s%(message)s%(reset)s"
    logging.root.setLevel(LOG_LEVEL)
    formatter = ColoredFormatter(LOGFORMAT, log_colors=log_colors)
    stream = logging.StreamHandler()
    stream.setLevel(LOG_LEVEL)
    stream.setFormatter(formatter)
    log_ = logging.getLogger('pythonConfig')
    log_.setLevel(LOG_LEVEL)
    log_.addHandler(stream)
    return log_
```

Thanks!

Comment: possibly a duplicate of: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343227/can-pythons-logging-format-be-modified-depending-on-the-message-log-level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343227/can-pythons-logging-format-be-modified-depending-on-the-message-log-level)

Comment: See that specific and detailled answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/8349076/7212686

Comment: The duplicate is for Python 2. The accepted answer has a link to the Python 3 solution, which is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14844970/modifying-logging-message-format-based-on-message-logging-level-in-python3 . That is likely a better duplicate.