# How to include the logging event level SMTPHandler subject line?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, smtplib

The SMTPHandler requires a "subject" to be included when [it is initialized](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.handlers.SMTPHandler).

How can the subject line include the level of the event that generated the email? For example:

```
import logging
from logging.handlers import SMTPHandler

logger = logging.getLogger('test_logger')

email = SMTPHandler(*credentials, subject="class_name")

logger.addHandler(email)

logs.info('Info Test')

logs.error('Error Test')
```

How to make the subject list for `logs.info('Info Test')` be `INFO: class_name` and `logs.Error('Error Test')` be `ERROR: class_name`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Python's logging format be modified depending on the message log level?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343227/can-pythons-logging-format-be-modified-depending-on-the-message-log-level)

Comment: The two questions are different as the Formatted works for the content of the log message, and has nothing to do with the `SMTPHandler` subject line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, you need to subclass `SMTPHandler` and override the [`getSubject` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.handlers.SMTPHandler.getSubject), which says:

> If you want to specify a subject line which is record-dependent, override this method.