# python logging with contextual format

Tags: python, logging

Using python 3.8, I'd like to use `logging`, and record with different formats according to `level`.

With `logging.DEBUG`, my output format would be `"%(asctime)s %(filename)s, line %(lineno)d : %(name)s %(levelname)s %(message)s"`, and above this level, it would be `"%(asctime)s %(levelname)s  %(message)s"`.

```
logger.debug("debug message")
logger.info("info message")
```

I've browsed through the doc. with LoggerAdapter, ContextFilter, ... I could not find any solution. Any idea ?

Comment: See also : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343227/can-pythons-logging-format-be-modified-depending-on-the-message-log-level

Comment: Why don't you use the solution from the answer in your comment?

Answer (score -1):

Use can use these code to set format of the logging and level parameter will determine the min level logged

```
logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.DEBUG,
    format='%(asctime)s | %(name)s | %(levelname)s | %(message)s',
    datefmt='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S'
)
```

Comment: Out of scope. In your solution, the message in logging.info() is as rich as the one of logging.debug().

Comment: If want that, you must create many loggers, for example: debug_logger and info_logger and set separated config for each logger. Use info_logger.info() and debug_logger() instead of logging.info() and logging.debug()