# How can I format log messages based on severity in Python's logging?

Tags: python

From reading the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.9/howto/logging.html#logging-basic-tutorial) about logging, I know I can use the `basicConfig` for example to set the format of logging records, such as:

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(format="%(levelname)s - %(message)s")
```

for example.

My question is, can I specify different formats for different levels? What I'm trying to achieve is to format logging  records to Azure Pipelines logging commands so that for examle the Python code:

```
logging.error("some error")
```

Will be printed as:

```
##[error]some error
```

Now I know I can use the `%(levelname)` but I don't want to rely on the correspondence between Azure Pipelines logging commands to Python's "logging" module. For example, in Python's logging there's `info` level, but not in Azure Pipelines.

Comment: I think the best way to achieve this is building your own wrapper class above the **logging** module. A similar approach was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343227/can-pythons-logging-format-be-modified-depending-on-the-message-log-level/8349076).

Comment: There might be an alternate avenue: does the Python logging module allow you to specify custom log levels? It's mentioned that it's possible [here](https://docs.python.org/3.9/howto/logging.html#custom-levels) but with no further elaboration on how to do so

Answer (score 0):

There's an [Azure doc specifically for Python logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/azure-sdk-logging) which you might find useful. If I understand it correctly (I've never used Azure), you should be able to send it Python logs without doing anything special.

However, the log messages shown as part of [this Azure chart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash) are plainly a bit different. If you want your messages to appear like that, one option is to set some custom levels with the level-names Azure prefers. The doc you referenced has a [section on that](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#custom-levels), although it warns against doing it in complex libraries.

If you want to reuse standard levels, but rename "info" -> "command" or some such, you're probably going to need a separate formatter for each such rename.