# Python | change text color in shell

Tags: python, shell

I was wondering if anyone knows how to set the color of the text that shows up in the shell. I noticed the 'ls' uses a couple different colors when printing out information to the screen (on my Linux box), was wondering if I could take advantage of that in Python.

Comment: it's a duplicate question and has been already answered by me here => https://stackoverflow.com/a/70599663/3057246

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Use Curses or ANSI escape sequences.  Before you start spouting escape sequences, you should check that stdout is a tty.  You can do this with `sys.stdout.isatty()`.  Here's a function pulled from a project of mine that prints output in red or green, depending on the status, using ANSI escape sequences:

```
def hilite(string, status, bold):
    attr = []
    if status:
        # green
        attr.append('32')
    else:
        # red
        attr.append('31')
    if bold:
        attr.append('1')
    return '\x1b[%sm%s\x1b[0m' % (';'.join(attr), string)
```

Comment: +1 especially for `sys.stdout.isatty()`

Comment: It's also nice to have an override for the case that the output is not a tty, but you still want the colour - say you are just filtering lines with sed or grep

Comment: `unbuffer` can do that, so you're not stuck if there's no override.

Comment: @Ignacio, cool I wonder why debian doesn't have an unbuffer package :(

Comment: @gnibbler: unbuffer is part of expect.

Comment: found it - debian hides it in `expect-dev` under the name `expect_unbuffer`

Comment: Is that supposed to work in a Windows 7 console? Because when I call `print( hilite( "toto", True, True ) )` it prints `←[32;1mtoto←[0m` with no color....(note that `sys.stdout.isatty()` returns me `True`)

Answer (score 12):

I just described very popular library [clint](https://github.com/kennethreitz/clint). Which has more features apart of coloring the output on terminal.

By the way it support MAC, Linux and Windows terminals.

Here is the example of using it:

**Installing (in Ubuntu)**

```
pip install clint
```

**To add color to some string**

```
colored.red('red string')
```

**Example: Using for color output (django command style)**

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from clint.textui import colored


class Command(BaseCommand):
    args = ''
    help = 'Starting my own django long process. Use ' + colored.red('<Ctrl>+c') + ' to break.'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        self.stdout.write('Starting the process (Use ' + colored.red('<Ctrl>+c') + ' to break)..')
        # ... Rest of my command code ...
```

Answer (score 5):

All the major color codes are given at https://www.siafoo.net/snippet/88

Comment: This website's security certificate has expired.  Can anyone verify that this is a safe website?

Comment: @BlackVegetable, yeah, it looks the same as before.  Also, you can view it [HTTP](http://www.siafoo.net/snippet/88) if you prefer.  I'll contact them to let them know about the cert.

Comment: even if you do trust it, @BlackVegetable, you get a proxy error

Answer (score 4):

[`curses`](http://docs.python.org/library/curses.html) will allow you to use colors properly for the type of terminal that is being used.

Answer (score 2):

have a look at http://www.pixelbeat.org/talks/python/ls.py

Answer (score -4):

This is so simple to do on a PC: Windows OS:
Send the os a command to change the text:
    import os

```
os.system('color a') #green text
print 'I like green' 
raw_input('do you?')
```

Comment: This sets the color globally, for the entire terminal, not for some characters on it.

Comment: Doesn't work at all in the spyder console or spyder IPython console.