# how to change color in python shell?

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python | change text color in shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330245/python-change-text-color-in-shell)

I have made a code to calculate the brightness temperature and i want to highlight the final result in different color. How to change the text color from default blue to red over the white background in python shell ?

Comment: you can check .. http://packages.python.org/pycolors/,, http://pypi.python.org/pypi/termcolor