# Python: Changing color of Progress Bar (CLINT)

Tags: python, python-2.7, progress-bar, python-2.x, clint

Can anybody tell me how can I change the color of the progress bar of the `CLINT` module?

I tried with module `termcolor` but failed.

Answer (score 0):

`CLINT` has its own way of setting colours.

```
from clint.textui import colored
red_text = colored.red("Red Text")   # This is a 'red-string' object
print(red_text)     # This will be printed in red.
```

Maybe with that you can change the colours of the characters printed as your progress bar.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16630004/7285313