# How does Pywikipedia manage colours on the command line?

Tags: python, colors, cmd, pywikibot

I have always thought that there is no possible formatting on the command line, as everything I have read says.

However, I recently discovered that pywikipedia (a python bot framework for automatically editing wikipedia-style wikis) can output text to the command line (the normal windows `cmd.exe`) in different colours!

This is the python syntax:

```
import wikipedia
wikipedia.output(u"\03{lightpurple}"+s+"\03{default}")
```

You have to use `wikipedia.output()` (or `pywikibot.output()`) but not just `print`.

The [online pywikipedia repository](http://svn.wikimedia.org/viewvc/pywikipedia/trunk/pywikipedia/wikipedia.py?revision=10153&view=markup) (around line 7990) gives a short explanation:

```
text can contain special sequences to create colored output. These
consist of the escape character \03 and the color name in curly braces,
e. g. \03{lightpurple}. \03{default} resets the color.
```

I think it is probably to do with this line:

```
ui.output(text, toStdout = toStdout)
```

But I can't find any reference to a `ui` class.

So how does Pywikipedia manage it?

Comment: Here's a tool that can do it - the source code might be informative: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/clint/

Comment: Where did you read that? Nearly every terminal is capable of color output.

Comment: @Thomas, Thanks for that. Although I haven't found the definate answer, there are some links and stuff in there that will help.

Comment: @Wooble, so I have realised... :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I color Python logging output?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/384076/how-can-i-color-python-logging-output)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you can use the ANSI Code on Windows.
But in Python you could write make it like that :

```
 >>> print "\033[0;32m"+ "Green" +"\033[0m"
 Green
```

I saw it [here](http://nezzen.net/2008/06/23/colored-text-in-python-using-ansi-escape-sequences/).

Answer (score 0):

> I think it is probably to do with this line:
>
> `ui.output(text, toStdout = toStdout)`
>
> But I can't find any reference to a ui class.

**How does Pywikibot manage colors on the command line**

Indeed this is tricky.

You have found the color codes already like \03{lightblue} an \03{default}; all of them can be found [here](https://doc.wikimedia.org/pywikibot/master/api_ref/pywikibot.userinterfaces.html#pywikibot.userinterfaces.terminal_interface_base.colors). There is also a function [`color_format()`](https://doc.wikimedia.org/pywikibot/master/api_ref/pywikibot.tools.html?highlight=color_format#pywikibot.tools.formatter.color_format) which automatically handles the escape sequence.
The [`UI`](https://doc.wikimedia.org/pywikibot/master/api_ref/pywikibot.userinterfaces.html) class has the private [`_print()`](https://doc.wikimedia.org/pywikibot/master/_modules/pywikibot/userinterfaces/terminal_interface_base.html#UI.support_color) method which handles all color stuff and delegates the hardware sequence to the [`encounter_color()`](https://doc.wikimedia.org/pywikibot/master/search.html?q=encounter_color) method. There are implementations for Windows and Linux yet.

But you are right, there is no direct reference to terminal interface UI class.

There is a function `set_interface()` in [`bot`](https://doc.wikimedia.org/pywikibot/master/_modules/pywikibot/bot.html) module which assigns the `UI` class to the `ui` userinterface used by Pywikibot. The `'terminal'` module for `userinterfaces_terminal_interface` is set inside `config.py` which is the Pywikibot configuarion file which can be overridden by a `user_config.py`. There is also a `buffer_interface` mostly used by tests. Other interfaces from older branch like `cgi`, `tkinter`, `wxpython` aren't supported currently.