# friendly query logging in SQLAlchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy

From a user's perspective, SQLAlchemy's query logging seems a little too verbose and even somewhat cryptic at times:

```
2015-10-02 13:51:39,500 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2015-10-02 13:51:39,502 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT anon_1.shelves_title AS anon_1_shelves_title, ..., anon_1.shelves_created_at AS anon_1_shelves_created_at, anon_1.shelves_updated_at AS anon_1_shelves_updated_at, products_1.id AS products_1_id, products_1.title AS products_1_title
FROM (SELECT shelves.title AS shelves_title, ..., shelves.created_at AS shelves_created_at, shelves.updated_at AS shelves_updated_at
FROM shelves
WHERE shelves.title = ?
 LIMIT ? OFFSET ?) AS anon_1 LEFT OUTER JOIN products AS products_1 ON anon_1.shelves_title = products_1.shelf_title
2015-10-02 13:51:39,502 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ('sample', 1, 0)
2015-10-02 13:51:39,503 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ROLLBACK
```

(not necessarily representative, but hopefully sufficient to illustrate the issue)

Arguably Ruby on Rails is a good reference here, providing concise and colorized output of the actual database queries:

[image: Rails SQL logging]

(via https://code.google.com/p/pylonsquerybar/#What_Others_Have_Done)

Is there a simple way to get similar output for SQLAlchemy? (The aforementioned Pylons Query Bar doesn't seem to be designed for framework-agnostic reuse.)

Answer (score 4):

you can set any format to logger, you can get logger:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='db.log')
logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy.engine').setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

how to set colors and format see here:
[How can I color Python logging output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384076/how-can-i-color-python-logging-output)

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't really address the core issue of formatting the actual SQL queries, removing noise and providing some easier to comprehend structure.

Comment: what is "noise"? <br> 2015-10-02 13:51:39,503 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ROLLBACK<br>2015-10-02 13:51:39,500 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine BEGIN (implicit) ?

Comment: Yeah; pretty much anything that isn't the actual SQL query. Ideally, that query should also be displayed exactly as it's being sent to the database.

Comment: sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine BEGIN -- related to transactions, good to have such info in the logs.  about: "WHERE shelves.title = ?
 LIMIT ? OFFSET ?)" vs ruby picture: " where (person.id=7)", here you see 2 different query types. "?"--"sql parameter ". you can check sql statements in the sql profiler, you will see 2 different types. statement with parameters is better(because of server sql parser cache). generally you see exactly what sql server do with sqlalchemy call

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, below's what we came up with. It adds alternating colorization, which doesn't solve the noise issue, but at least provides some visual distinction.

```py
import logging

import colorama


def configure_sql_logging():
    sqla_logger = logging.getLogger("sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine")
    sqla_logger.propagate = False
    sqla_logger.addHandler(SQLLogger(colors=["MAGENTA", "CYAN"]))


class SQLLogger(logging.StreamHandler):

    def __init__(self, *args, colors, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.colors = colors
        self.colorizer = Colorizer(self.stream, colors[0])

    def emit(self, *args, **kwargs):
        with self.colorizer:
            super().emit(*args, **kwargs)

        # cycle colors
        if self.colorizer.active:
            self.colors.append(self.colors.pop(0))
            self.colorizer.color = self.colors[0]


class Colorizer:

    def __init__(self, stream, color):
        self.stream = stream
        self.active = stream.isatty()
        if self.active:
            colorama.init()
            self.color = color

    def __enter__(self):
        if self.active:
            self.stream.write(getattr(colorama.Fore, self.color))

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        if self.active:
            self.stream.write(colorama.Fore.RESET)
```