# How to colorize text in terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal

Need to print colored block in terminal. I wrote this:

```
from termcolor import colored
...
print(colored('\u2588\u2588\', '#%s' %(color)))
```

Where `color` is color in hex, seems like `termcolor` can't work with hex
Also tried module `colored`:

```
import colored
...
color_t = fg('#'+color)
```

but Python raises `KeyError: '#4e1747'` (random color)
What's wrong?

Comment: Have You even bothered to read manual for any of those libraries? First one supports 8 colors, while second supports 256 colors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I color Python logging output?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/384076/how-can-i-color-python-logging-output)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found answer

```
message = 'some string'
hex_color = '#4e1747'
r, g, b = [int(hex_color[i:i+2], 16) for i in range(1, len(hex_color), 2)]
print("\x1b[38;2;{r};{g};{b}m{message}\x1b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Colorama](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama) package, it provides cross-platform coloring of terminal output and is very easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

This will print the hex string in Bright Green.
This is a fun color ANSI escape "\033["

```
import sys
print("\033[1;32;40m '\u2588\u2588\\' \n")
```

Good sources:
http://www.jwrr.com/content/Console-Escape-Sequences/
http://ozzmaker.com/add-colour-to-text-in-python/

Comment: The problem is that I'm having unknown color