# logging python - custom formatter with colour

Tags: python, logging, colors

I am using logging module in Python and I already use a custom formatter that just changes the format of the message depending on level.

As I use a lot of message in the tool I am writing I wonder if there is a way to write a log message with a colour

I don't want it to be definitive (i.e. add colours in the formatter class) I would like to write a log message

```
logging.info('i am doing this, wait...')
```

in red (or any other colour)

regards

Comment: have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384076/how-can-i-color-python-logging-output

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56944256 look for my answer, compatible with python 3

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://plumberjack.blogspot.com/2010/12/colorizing-logging-output-in-terminals.html) is a description of how you can do this. Available via the [`logutils`](https://pypi.org/project/logutils/) package from PyPI (I'm the maintainer).