# django logging: DJANGO_COLORS does nothing (macos)

Tags: python, django

I'm on MACOS terminal. I'm trying to print colored output  running a django test. I'm setting, from the terminal

```
export DJANGO_COLORS="error=yellow/blue,blink;notice=magenta"
```

(also tried `DJANGO_COLORS="light"` and others.

Then, from django test code

```
print(os.environ['DJANGO_COLORS'])
logger.error("test")
```

and run

```
python manage.py test
```

The first line verifies that the environment variable is set correctly. But the next line prints normally, without coloring. What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [`django-admin` syntax coloring documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/django-admin/#syntax-coloring) that deals with `DJANGO_COLORS` (emphasis mine):

> The **django-admin / manage.py commands** will use pretty color-coded output if your terminal supports ANSI-colored output.

That doesn't mention output from the `logging` package. The referenced commands use [a specific kind of `stdout.write` invocation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-management-commands/#django.core.management.BaseCommand.style) that should take `DJANGO_COLORS` into account.

If what you want is colors in your logging, you might want to check out the answers to [this relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384076/how-can-i-color-python-logging-output).

Comment: So, no built-in way for colorful logging?

Comment: If you check out the last link, I think you should be able to get colorful logging working. It's just not Django-specific, and not nearly as pretty.

Answer (score 0):

```py
from django.core.management import color_style
sys.stdout.write(color_style().WARNING("Colorful!"))
```