# How to use logging with colors (only on stream)?

Tags: python, logging

**TL;DR:**
How can I have the stream handler to print logs with colors, and the file handler log them without the literal code characters? 
Any approach is fine with me, as long I'm still using standart python libraries.

--

I have been looking how to add color to the logger when it's streamed. 
**Also I would like to use the standart python logging library.**

I found this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7995762/11037602

It served me well, the issue is that my logger logs into stream **and** into file. And the file gets the escape/colors characters aswell, like this:

> - [1;33mWARNING[1;0m - run - log

Instead of:

> - WARNING - run - log

My code:

```
def setup_logger():
  logger = logging.getLogger()

  #Code suggested in SO question
  logging.addLevelName( logging.WARNING, "\033[1;31m%s\033[1;0m" % logging.getLevelName(logging.WARNING))
  logging.addLevelName( logging.ERROR, "\033[1;41m%s\033[1;0m" % logging.getLevelName(logging.ERROR))

  logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG) 
  formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(funcName)s - %(message)s')

  fh = logging.FileHandler('file.log')
  fh.setFormatter(formatter)
  logger.addHandler(fh)

  sh = logging.StreamHandler()
  sh.setFormatter(formatter)
  logger.addHandler(sh)

  return logger
```

As I said, this works, however it also records the characters into the file log.

If you click in 'show 2 more comments' on the question that I linked, user @lesnik suggested put the answer's code inside if statement, I'm assuming he meant something like this:

```
if sys.stderr.isatty():
  logging.addLevelName( logging.WARNING, "\033[1;31m%s\033[1;0m" % logging.getLevelName(logging.WARNING))
  logging.addLevelName( logging.ERROR, "\033[1;41m%s\033[1;0m" % logging.getLevelName(logging.ERROR))
```

**EDIT:** Corrected the typo (pointed out by @Brad Solomon) but just adding this if statement **didn't solve my problem**. The characters are still logged in file.

To sum it up, how can I have the stream handler to print logs with colors, and the file handler log them without the literal code characters? Any approach is fine with me, as long I'm still using standart python libraries.

Comment: Do you have a file named `sys.py` somewhere locally?

Comment: No. Also tested in directly in the python shell.

Comment: Typo: `stderr`, not `sdterr`.

Comment: Corrected the typo and now the code runs, however, the **issue remains**. The characters are still logged in the file. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What about using this module?
https://coloredlogs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/