# Check terminal color

Tags: python, bash

I'd like to print some errors in red and then go back to the standard color of the terminal. I'm doing this using the same bash commands e.g. \033[1;31;40m

In python it would be:

```py
print ('\033[1;31;40mERROR:\033[1;37;40m')
```

the problem is that this works for my own terminal but if someone would have some different coloring the exit coloring wouldn't be the same

So I was wondering if there's a way in python to know what is the value of PS1 in bash or maybe some approach even more general to go back to the original coloring

Comment: These are interpreted by the terminal, not `bash`. How can you know which terminal  I'm using? FWIW, all the terminals I've used in GNU/Linux has support for the ANSI escape sequences.

Comment: Look for environment variables like `TERM`, `COLORTERM`.

Comment: Probably a better solution to use a colored logger module. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384076/how-can-i-color-python-logging-output

Answer (score 0):

Using `0m` will reset the color. print (`Something \033[0m`)

Reference: [here](https://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting)