# How can I create color red debug logger error message?

Tags: python

I have a debug logger option in my codes. I have a logger.debug and logger.error function. But I want to do just error log by a color Red. How can I do this ? When I try to these codes:https://coloredlogs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readme.html
I get every log messages red.

This is library logger create funtion:

```
def create_logger(name="dummy", level=logging.DEBUG, record_format=None):
    """Create a logger according to the given settings"""
    if record_format is None:
        record_format = "%(asctime)s\t%(levelname)s\t%(module)s.%(funcName)s\t%(threadName)s\t%(message)s"

    logger = logging.getLogger("modbus_tk")
    logger.setLevel(level)
    formatter = logging.Formatter(record_format)
    if name == "udp":
        log_handler = LogitHandler(("127.0.0.1", 1975))
    elif name == "console":
        log_handler = ConsoleHandler()
    elif name == "dummy":
        log_handler = DummyHandler()
    else:
        raise Exception("Unknown handler %s" % name)
    log_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(log_handler)
    return logger
```

Comment: do you mean the color red?

Comment: yes color red logger.error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I color Python logging output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384076/how-can-i-color-python-logging-output)

Comment: No this is custom logger but I want to change library logger color on create_logger just color error logs