# PyCharm logging colors are always red

Tags: python, logging, pycharm, console

I am using Python's built-in `logging` library to log information, but I cannot find a way to set these colors so that I can distinguish them from actual error colors.

[image]

I have tried to change **Run** > **Edit Configurations...** > **Configuration** > **Emulate terminal** settings.

I have tried to use *Grep Console Plugin*.

I have tried creating another script for log file, as suggest [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56944256)
But this gives me following result:

[image]

Here is how I set the configuration of logger.

```py
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(levelname)s:%(message)s')

logging.debug("this is debug")
logging.info("this is info")
logging.warning("this is warning")
logging.error("this is error")
logging.critical("this is critical")
# this needs to be RED.
print("10 / 0 =", 10 / 0)
```

I would like to use some (reasonable) color scheme, not RED colors for info logs, similar to shown here:

[image]

I am using the following following version of PyCharm:

```
PyCharm 2020.3.1 (Professional Edition)
Build #PY-203.6682.86, built on August 12, 2021
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.