# Python logging filter being applied to all handlers when only added to one

Tags: python, python-logging

I am adding logging to a Python project, and I wish to log to both terminal and file. To do this I am using a `streamHandler` and a `fileHandler`.

To make it easier to quickly differentiate between log levels, I wish to add colour to the `levelname` for the logs that are output to the terminal, and to achieve this I have added a filter.

However, despite the filter only being applied to the `streamHandler`, messages in the log file are seeing the colour code applied. How can this be, given the filter is not added to the `fileHandler`?

#### Example Code

Note that the filter in this example only includes a format for `logging.ERROR`, as this will log to both terminal and file. But in reality I have a format for all log levels.

```py
import logging


class ColourLevelNameFilter(logging.Filter):

    FORMATS = {
        logging.ERROR: '\x1b[031m' + '{0}' + '\x1b[0m',
    }

    def filter(self, record):
        
        levelname_format = self.FORMATS.get(record.levelno)
        record.levelname = levelname_format.format(record.levelname)

        return True
    
def main():

    time_format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
    text_format = '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s => %(message)s'
    formatter = logging.Formatter(text_format, time_format)

    stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    stream_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    stream_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    stream_handler.addFilter(ColourLevelNameFilter())

    log_file = 'test-error.log'
    file_handler = logging.FileHandler(log_file, 'w')
    file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    file_handler.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
        
    logger = logging.getLogger('my-app')
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    logger.addHandler(stream_handler)
    logger.addHandler(file_handler)

    logger.error('Testing logging of error.')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You're misusing the filters and modifying the `LogRecord` object in them. Filters aren't meant for that purpose.

Comment: Ah, so the log record is not per handler then? That being the case, is there anything I can use to achieve my goal?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I color Python logging output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384076/how-can-i-color-python-logging-output)

Comment: Sadly I don't think so. That answer (which I had already investigated) colors the whole log, not just the level name.

Comment: That's basically a minor modification to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384076/how-can-i-color-python-logging-output/56944256#56944256) you just have to change the format strings in the `FORMATS` dictionary so that the color is specifically applied to the level name.

Comment: The trouble with that is that the format must then be explicitly set in the formatter, rather than being dynamic.
I think I'm starting to lean towards separate loggers...

Comment: OK, got it, and it doesn't need the format of the message at all. Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: Well technically you could implement a custom style like the default [PercentStyle](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/67688609d21c759295b773407057724581a1e3c2/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L436) and have your formatter use it but its not really public API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments to my question, a Filter is the wrong thing to use in this instance, so I ended up using a customer formatter and rather than editing the `record`, I amended the text that is returned by the formatter.

**Update:** Update `msg.replace` to find and replace `f'{record.asctime} {record.levelname}'`, minimising the risk of spurious coloured words appearing in the log output (see comments).

```py
import logging

class ColourFormatter(logging.Formatter):

    FORMATS = {
        logging.ERROR: '\x1b[031m' + '{0}' + '\x1b[0m',
    }
    
    def format(self, record: logging.LogRecord) -> str:

        levelname_format = self.FORMATS.get(record.levelno)
        colour_levelname = levelname_format.format(record.levelname)
        msg = super().format(record)
        msg = msg.replace(record.levelname, colour_levelname)

        levelname_format = self.FORMATS.get(record.levelno)
        colour_levelname = levelname_format.format(record.levelname)
        msg = msg.replace(f'{record.asctime} {record.levelname}', f'{record.asctime} {colour_levelname}')
    
        return msg

    
def main():

    time_format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
    text_format = '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s => %(message)s'
    formatter_stream = ColourFormatter(text_format, time_format)
    formatter_file = logging.Formatter(text_format, time_format)

    stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    stream_handler.setFormatter(formatter_stream)
    stream_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    log_file = 'test-error.log'
    file_handler = logging.FileHandler(log_file, 'w')
    file_handler.setFormatter(formatter_file)
    file_handler.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
        
    logger = logging.getLogger('my-app')
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    logger.addHandler(stream_handler)
    logger.addHandler(file_handler)

    logger.error('Testing logging of error.')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: `msg.replace` doesn't look well here: what if I logged `nothing to do: moving to ERROR state`? Since you know the whole format, I'd better replace text there (still not perfect - maybe there's static format part containing level - but less prone to logged messages edits).

Comment: @STerliakov - Good point, and to that point I have made an adjustment. As my logs are formatted with `%(asctime)s %(levelname)s` at the beginning, I can find and replace all of that. True, there is still a risk, but it's minor and in my case I know I won't be logging `asctime` as part of the message.