# Is there an Eclipse plugin to run system shell in the Console?

Tags: shell, eclipse-plugin

Do you know of any Eclipse plugin to run a system shell in the included console?
It would be awesome. Dolphin, KDE's file navigator, has this feature, you can press F4 and a console shows located on the directory you are standing.

It would be awesome to have a similar feature on Eclipse, with the shell located on the directory of the project/file you are working on.

Does this plugin exist?

If not, would it be too complicated to code such a plugin? I have no idea about eclipse plugin development (yet).

Comment: The justification given to close this is INVALID. "*tend to attract opinionated answers and spam*" ?? This question is very specific, and would elicit only very specific answers. This is getting out of hand.

Comment: Yeah, I don't use Eclipse anymore, but it's a "Yes, here's one of them" kind of question. It doesn't ask which one is the best, or if it's a good practice. Also, the accepted answer is pretty specific.

Comment: Check out EasyShell  https://github.com/anb0s/EasyShell it is very configurable. I use it with cmd and git bash on Windows.  There is also https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/tm-terminal if you want the shell to be a view in Eclipse, which works with cmd and git bash, etc.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

It exists, and it's built into Eclipse! Go to the Remote Systems view, and you'll see an entry for "Local". Right-click "Local Shells" and choose "Launch Shell."

You can't launch it directly from the project navigator. But you can right-click in the navigator and choose "Show in Remote Systems view". From there you can right-click the parent folder and choose "Launch Shell."

[Aptana](http://www.aptana.com/) also has a Terminal view, and a command to open the selected file in the terminal.

Comment: In case you haven't installed something that depends on it already, you will first have to do Install New Software -> General Purpose Tools -> Remote System Explorer End-User Runtime.

Comment: Very rough indeed. I tried running sbt in such a view, and it crashed.

Comment: Added note about Aptana.

Comment: I tried this solution but didn't work for me. If I right-click on 'Local Shells' and then select 'launch shell' this displays a so-called Remote Shell in Local. This shell actually does not response to commands (something I still don't understand). If instead of selecting 'launch shell' the option 'Commands>Shell Script>Open Terminal' is selected then a local terminal which actually works is displayed.

Comment: Local shell is deprecated, the suggested default replacement is TCF Terminal (Console) View, under Mobile and Device Development support

Comment: Just for reference since I was brand new to this: Go to Window->Show View->Other...->Remote Systems->Remote Systems to show the Remote Systems View

Comment: This requires a plugin (the Remote System Explorer plugin from Eclipse Marketplace) that may or may not come with whatever install of Eclipse you have.

Comment: There's a package *TM Terminal* that does the trick. After installing this one, there's a View *Terminal* available.

Answer (score 69):

You don't need a plugin (including the Remote System View plugin), you can do this with the basic platform. You just create an external tool configuration. I've added an image to demonstrate.

[image: screenshot from Mac of external tools configuration dialog with colored arrows]

**Orange Arrows:** Use the external tool button on the toolbar and select `External Tools Configuration...`. Click on `Program` then up above click on the `New launch configuration` icon.

**Green Arrows:** Use the `Name` field and name your new tool something clever like "Launch Shell".  In the `Location` area enter a shell command e.g. `/bin/bash`. A more generic approach would be to use `${env_var:SHELL}` which under the Mac (and I hope Linux) launches the default shell. Then in the `Working Directory` you can use the variable  `${project_loc}` to set the default directory to your current project location. This will mean that when you launch the tool, you have to make sure you have your cursor in an active project on the explorer or in an appropriate editor window.  Under the `Arguments` area use `-i` for interactive mode.

**Blue arrows:** Switch to the `Build` tab and uncheck `Build before launch`. Then switch to the `Common` tab and click to add your command to the favorites menu.  Now click `Apply` and `Close`. Make sure the console view is showing (`Window->Show View->Console`). Click on a project in the Package or Project Explorer or click in an editor window that has code for a project of interest. Then click on the external tool icon and select `Launch Shell`, you now have an interactive shell window in the console view.

In the lower left of the image you can see the tcsh shell in action.

**Windows Note:**
This also works in Windows but you use `${env_var:ComSpec}` in the location field and you can leave the arguments field blank.

Comment: Will that be external window?

Comment: Found answer by @Andre, and combined into this one.

Comment: No it opens the console window in the Eclipse console window.

Comment: I noticed you saw a similar answer below. I added comments to my edits explaining my thinking, but I thought I would post a direct answer to your question here in the comment.

Comment: I edited this answer adding a screenshot, but it is gone. Nevermind

Comment: I am getting this error: bash: no job control in this shell

Comment: This is an elegant solution, but the session it creates is not fully functional. I get the following error messages: 
`bash: cannot set terminal process group (1893): Inappropriate ioctl for device`
`bash: no job control in this shell`

Comment: Another issue: the <kbd>Tab</kbd> does not function.

Comment: I found that (at least under windows) using ${workspace_loc}\${project_name} works even when a simple file is selected in the navigator, while ${project_loc} gives me an error in that case. I'm using mintty (cygwin), it doesn't open in the eclipse console but I like it better than windows cmd ;) to make it work give this arguments instead of -i: "-e /bin/xhere /bin/bash.exe"

Comment: The `{project_loc}` is not working for me, I use `{container_loc}` instead which works better.

Answer (score 57):

[Eclipse TCF team](http://eclipse.org/tcf/) has just release terminal (SSH, Telnet, local)

originally named TCF Terminal, then renamed to TM Terminal

http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/tcf-terminals

Finally Windows and Linux all supported

[image]

[image]

Support for Git Bash on Windows is resolved [Bug 435014](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=435014).

This plugin is included into [Enide Studio 2014](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/enide-studio-2014-nodejs-javascript-and-java) and [Enide 2015](http://www.nodeclipse.org/enide/2015).

To access the terminal go to Window -> Show View -> Terminal or <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+T</kbd>

Comment: It needs some settings though...everytime I need to cd to the appropriate directory.

Comment: Wait for 1.3 released. If that would be not enough raise bug with request.

Comment: At this day and age this is the only functional solution. Make sure you install the TM Terminal version **4.0**.

Comment: I can't believe they nuked ability to right click a folder in Remote Systems and launch terminal. This is really undermines the usability.

Comment: @Paul Verest, How did you changed the colore scheme of the terminal ?

Comment: @MeladEzzat see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40459023/customize-theme-colors-of-eclipse-tm-terminal-plugin#43779152

Comment: has been renamed to `TM Terminal`

Comment: For having *TM Terminal* start *bash* with the current Eclipse user not having a login shell ("*This account is currently not available*"), I had to make the following configurations under Eclipse: *Preferences* → *Terminal* → *Local Terminal* → *Shell Command*: `/usr/bin/bash`; *Arguments* `-c bash`.

Answer (score 12):

[Terminal plug-in for Eclipse](https://code.google.com/archive/p/elt) provides a command line view (= INSIDE Eclipse), at the moment Linux and Mac OS X only, Windows is missing. For Windows, use JW's aproach.

[image]
<sub>(source: [developerblogs.com](http://alexruiz.developerblogs.com/files/2012/07/terminal21.png))</sub>

Update 1:
They are working on Windows support, see this [issue](https://code.google.com/archive/p/elt/issues/18) and a basic [implementation](https://code.google.com/archive).

Update 2: Not working on it since Aug 2013.

Comment: They are not working since August 2013. Quote from http://alexruiz.developerblogs.com/?p=2428 "Alex Ruiz August 3, 2013 at 12:49 pm

    Unfortunately I’m no longer maintaining this project, mostly due to a lack of spare time."

Comment: From the solutions I've tried this worked best for me, thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Add C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe as an external tool. Once run, you can then access it via the normal eclipse console.

http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-open-a-windows-command-prompt-in-my-console.html

[image]
<sub>(source: [avajava.com](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/eclipse/how-do-i-open-a-windows-command-prompt-in-my-console/how-do-i-open-a-windows-command-prompt-in-my-console-05.gif))</sub>

Comment: use /bin/bash for linux. however path completion does not work (Luna)

Answer (score 5):

Simply create a new **external tool configuration** (from Eclipse Run -> External Tools)

*for example - To open Cygwin terminal on the current resource directory:*

**Location:**

```
C:\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe
```

**Working Directory:**

```
${container_loc}
```

**Arguments:**

```
-i /Cygwin-Terminal.ico  
-"cygpath -p '${container_loc}' | xargs cd"
```

Comment: you can also use ${env_var:ComSpec} as the program to execute, and add as arguments: /C start C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe --login -i, or omit the --login -i to start bash in the directory specified by eclipse

Comment: How can I open multiple, using this method?  They all seem to pile into one console view.

Answer (score 4):

I really like [StartExplorer](http://basti1302.github.com/startexplorer/) but it is a contextual launcher rather than in - IDE shell so not sure if that is what you want

Answer (score 3):

[Aptana Studio 3](http://www.aptana.com/products/studio3) includes such terminal. I found it to be very similar to native terminal compared to what's mentioned in other answers.

Comment: Aptana is mainly focused on web development

Answer (score 3):

The best solution I have been able to find is [TCF Terminals 1.2 (Luna)](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/tcf-terminals#.U_JYWfldV8E).

You start off with a Windows command prompt.
[image]

If you like git bash, you can get git bash going inside it like this:
[image: Eclipse with TCF Terminals 1.2 and running Git Bash]
The trick is the command:

```
D:\Apps\Git\bin\sh.exe --login -i
```

Change this command path to wherever you installed git. The arguments --login -i are key.

Answer (score 2):

... just a little bit late :)
you might give a try at http://code.google.com/p/tarlog-plugins/. It gives you options like `open shell` and `open explorer` from Project Explorer context menu.

There's also http://sourceforge.net/projects/explorerplugin/ but it seems kind of stuck at 2009.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the Termial view to ssh/telnet to your local machine.  Doesn't have that funny input box for commands.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend [EasyShell](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/easyshell), which features 'open' (console), 'run', 'explore', and 'copy path'.

Comment: In Luna, Easy Shell is working only in Project Explorer view, not in Navigator view, unfortunately.

Comment: EasyShell opens a system terminal application, it does not provide an Eclipse embedded shell.

Comment: This is what i was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this to get a native shell...it uses the same GTK widget the gnome-terminal uses so the behavior should be nearly identical.

http://github.com/maihde/Eclipse-Terminal

Comment: Not updated for 2 years

Comment: Not updated for 8 years

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse 3.7, I found a terminal view plugin that I installed through Eclipse Marketplace. Details are as follow:

> Local Terminal (Incubation)
>   http://market.eclipsesource.com/yoxos/node/org.eclipse.tm.terminal.local.feature.group
>
> A terminal emulation for local shells and external tools.
>   Requires CDT Core 7.0 or later. Works on Linux, Solaris and Mac. Includes Source.

Side note, this terminal does not execute `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` so you can do

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

and (if this isn't sourced by `.bash_profile)

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Update:

This is actually was base for [Terminal plug-in for Eclipse](http://code.google.com/p/elt/) fork. Quote from http://alexruiz.developerblogs.com/?p=2428

> Uwe Stieber July 23, 2013 at 12:57 am
>
> Alex, why not aiming for rejoining your work with the original TM Terminal? I’ve checked and haven’t found any bugzilla asking for missing features or pointing out bugs. There had been changes to the original Terminal control, so I’m not sure if all of your original reasons to clone it are still true.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out about [WickedShell](http://www.wickedshell.net/), but it seems to work wrong with GNU/Linux and bash. Seems like some sort of encoding issue, all the characters in my prompt are displayed wrong.

Seems to be the best (only) tool for the job anyways, so I'll give it some more testing and see if it's good enough. I'll contact the developer anyways about this issue.

Comment: A warning: I installed wicked shell and started getting "Unexpected error" dialogs. So, If you get these also, just uninstall it.