# Eclipse (STS) + Maven

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, plugins, console, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I basically have 2 questions:

- Is there a way to invoke maven console from eclipse? (where I could write `eclipse:eclipse`, and it started building eclipse project)
- Where does [STS](http://www.springsource.com/products/sts) unpack it's maven? I'd like to add that path to env variables, so that I could use it from my windows console.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Is there a way to invoke maven console from eclipse? (where I could write eclipse:eclipse, and it started building eclipse project)

You could [open a shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1562600/is-there-an-eclipse-plugin-to-run-system-shell-in-the-console) inside eclipse , cd into the right directory and run the maven console from there. But, when using M2Eclipse (see next point), you're not supposed to run `eclipse:eclipse`.

> Where does STS unpack it's maven? I'd like to add that path to env variables, so that I could use it from my windows console.

STS bundles M2Eclipse which comes with an embedded version of Maven (so it doesn't "unpack" Maven). But you can Configure M2Eclipse to use an external version. Go to **window > Preference > Maven > Installations** and **Add...** your external install:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try the m2eclipse plugin from sonatype and you can eliminate use of 'mvn eclipse:eclipse' altogether.  After installing m2eclipse and restarting eclipse, select File->Import->Maven->Existing Maven project.  Browse to your maven project and select it.  The m2eclipse plugin reads the pom and creates an eclipse project (this is the step that 'mvn eclipse:eclipse' gives).  There are other useful features of the m2eclipse plugin including pom editor.

m2eclipse project is moving out of sonatype into the eclipse foundation project page  and will be released on the Indigo train.

See this page for more info on m2eclipse: http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/