# How do I get to the command line in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, macos

I can't figure out how to get to the command line in Eclipse.  I am using a mac.

Comment: Your question is ambiguous.  Can you be more specific?  Do you want the command line for Eclipse itself or for some Android app?

Comment: I am only looking for the Eclipse command line

Comment: Why is this question tagged Android?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you are asking for is local terminal. There are several option for Eclipse [Is there an Eclipse plugin to run system shell in the Console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1562600/is-there-an-eclipse-plugin-to-run-system-shell-in-the-console)

and you are lucky because there is great plugin for MacOS

UPDATE: there is new TM Terminal http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/tcf-terminals for all OSes.

[Terminal plug-in for Eclipse](https://code.google.com/archive/p/elt) provides a command line view (= INSIDE Eclipse), at the moment Linux and Mac OS X only.

[image]
<sub>(source: [developerblogs.com](http://alexruiz.developerblogs.com/files/2012/07/terminal21.png))</sub>

Answer (score 15):

In the Eclipse Menubar select Window->Show View-> Other

Find or type "Terminal" in the filter box

You should now see a Terminal view in the bottom pane.
In the icon section for that bottom pane you'll see an icon that looks like a very stylized terminal window with a plus-sign on it.

Click it and select "New Terminal Connection in current view", and then use the resulting dialog to create either a telnet or ssh connection to "localhost" depending on what you have available on your local system.

This works on Eclipse Indigo Java EE edition, with no additional plugins installed. I don't know if it was available in previous releases.

Comment: i don't have Terminal or the icon you are talking about in my eclipse. any ideas?

Comment: This answers the question, but it would be way more useful if the terminal could open in your current project directory. On Windows, I'm going to continue to right-click the project, Show in Explorer, and type `cmd` in the address bar.

Comment: Good advice, but it doesn't work for those who install the minimal "Eclipse Platform" IDE, at least for Eclipse 2019-09. They may do better to install something from the Eclipse Marketplace (after installing the Eclipse Marketplace itself).

Comment: There's a package *TM Terminal* that does the trick. After installing this one, there's a View *Terminal* available.

Answer (score 4):

I use the Aptana Studio plugin and it provides Eclipse with a terminal utility opened this way:

```
Window -> Show View -> Terminal
```

I don't think Eclipse comes with a terminal out of the box. You can add command line arguments to Java programs:

```
Right Click -> Run As -> Run Configurations -> Run As -> Arguments
```

When you run Android apps from within Eclipse, it's really just Eclipse proxy-ing`adb` commands to the OS. With this in mind, even though I develop my Android apps in Eclipse, I manage the emulator from the outside using a plain old terminal, for increased speed and control.

Comment: @Aaron Apologies. That was part of my Aptana Studio plugin.

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse version 2021-06, you can open a terminal by clicking on ***Window*** > ***Show View*** > ***Terminal***

[image]

Go to the terminal and click "Open a Terminal" icon located on the top-right corner

[image]

Lastly, select the type of terminal you wish to open from the popup drop down list.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I should assume you are looking to give command line input in Eclipse:

- Right Click on the class file ( in the file explorer view )
- **Debug As** -> **Debug Configurations**
- A new dialog box opens - Click on **Arguments** tab
- Fill up the **Program arguments** text area suitably.