# (Eclipse) How to interact with console view?

Tags: eclipse, view, console, command, interactive

Eclipse uses console view as read-only.

How can I type command in console view? Is it possible? E.g: `ls`, `mvn install`...

**Edited:**

Thanks Ben and Kelly.

I understand I can interact with Eclipse's console when my application is running. However, I meant I want an embedded console as like as the one in Kate, Dolphin (press F4 in Dolphin)... So I can use bash script in Eclipse's console. Is that possible? Or is there a plugin for that? I have googled but perhaps my keywords were not right...

**Edited**

Edward has found duplicate question here: [Is there an Eclipse plugin to run system shell in the Console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1562600/is-there-an-eclipse-plugin-to-run-system-shell-in-the-console)

And it was answered  :-)

I don't know how to mark this one as solved. So I place message here, I got the answer.

**Edited**

But it is not useful. It doesn't have auto complete feature, when I need to type a long file name, or want a hint for a forgotten name,... it is worst :-(

Comment: It isn't read-only.  If you were to run a Java application that read from `System.in`, then you would be able to interact with it in the console.  Are you trying to spawn a shell in the console?

Comment: Thanks Edward. My bad question. I have edited it. Could you please review it and help me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an Eclipse plugin to run system shell in the Console?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1562600/is-there-an-eclipse-plugin-to-run-system-shell-in-the-console)

Comment: It's wonderful. I have been using external terminal with `Alt-Tab` for long time. Thank you very much, you save my fingers  :-D

Comment: I feel you. I hope you will get your answer one day :-)

Answer (score 2):

When the console is waiting for input it shows a green prompt that allows you type.

You can test it out by making a simple console application that reads from standard input.

Comment: Thanks, I understand it. That is my application is running. I meant I want an embedded console as like as the one in KWrite, Kate... I'll edit my question for more clear.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't using the `Scanner` class to read it from `System.in`. I was actually using the `Console` got from the `System.getConsole()` method which works when using a real console.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to think of the Eclipse console as if it were connected to a command-line process.  It is actually connected to the JVM used to execute your Java code.  Thus, it only shows output that your program sends to `System.out` and conversely only is available for input if the Java code you are running is requesting input from `System.in`.

A decent exercise would be to write a small Java program that redirects the input and output to a child process of your favorite shell, for example: http://www.devdaily.com/java/edu/pj/pj010016

Comment: Thank you, I understand it. But as I replied to @Ben, I'll edit my question for more clear.

Answer (score 0):

The Eclipse Console view is used for communicating with an executed program (typically Java, or similar). If you want to use it as a console, as mentioned in the comment under @Ben S's answer, the  [Target Management](http://eclipse.org/tm/) Eclipse project provides a view that can be used for that reason. I don't have it installed right now, so I cannot tell you the required plug-in/view name, but I have used it to connect to the local computer and works.

Comment: Thanks Zoltán, but I prefer the built-in solution of Edward. If I need TM in the future, I will go get it. Thanks again  :-)

Comment: Well, that's the same plug-in I was talking about. It might be built-in in some Eclipse distributions, but I am sure it's not built-in in all ones. E.g. it's not included in mine. :D But I'm glad if that suits you.