# Put control character to eclipse console

Tags: eclipse

How can I put a control character like CTRL+R into console in Eclipse under Linux?
I'm running a script inside Eclipse and it stops at some point. Then I need to continue it by typing Ctrl+R. This works fine if I do it in normal terminal but it doesn't work under Eclipse console.

Answer (score 0):

**Simply you can't**.

Console in thinked as input/output view, not as a kind of shell. Not only input capability is limited to simple keys but also output capability is truncated. You cannot, for example, manage a \b to the Eclipse console.

If you want use a shell *into* a Eclipse view and then launch your script, you can always open it, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1562667/1360888