# linux eclipse Remote-system shell

Tags: linux, eclipse, shell, ubuntu-12.04

I am trying to run commands on my local system (Ubuntu 12.04) through the Remote Systems view in Eclipse (Juno) as explained here: http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.rse.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftruncmdsview.html&cp=58_4_0

I open the local shell, but no command is executed after I press enter. Am I missing some configuration steps? I installed Eclipse by downloading and uncompressing the program, not through repositories.

Comment: What have you tried? What is the expected behavior? What error messages are you getting? Have you checked the logs and things like Wireshark to observe the action on the backend?

Comment: This SO question might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1562600/

Comment: @L0j1k I tried opening a local shell from the Remote System Perspective. There I type for example 'ls + enter' and I expect to get the directory listing of the folder where the terminal is located (~). Other commands doesn't response neither. After 'enter' nothing happens.

Comment: @d1001001 I found in your reference this project (http://code.google.com/p/elt/wiki/Home) and it works. Thanks!

Comment: I realized another solution: In the Remote System Explorer view. If you right-click on 'Local Shells' and then select 'launch shell' this displays a so-called Remote Shell in Local. This shell actually does not response to commands (something I still don't understand). If instead of selecting 'launch shell' the option 'Commands>Shell Script>Open Terminal' is selected then a local terminal which actually works is displayed.