# how to issue an adb command from built in eclipse UI in Android SDK

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Is there way in which I can run an adb command from inbuilt eclipse UI in Android SDK?
I need to find out if ECLIPSE UI already has this functionality, if not need to go about implementing it.
Till now I have been mainly using adb commands on command line.

If there is no such functionality would implementing a Eclipse plug-in would be the best way to handle this?
I want this as a feature, so I have already ruled out the use of "External tools Configuration" which needs to be configured individually for every project an end user builts.

EDIT:
I don't need another console, may it be inside eclipse or outside. What I want to write is a UI which works according to my specific need but abstracts away the command line details from the end user. Now I can still explore on how to do that, but I was looking for an existing example which does this for its specific need,through its UI and abstracts away the details of command line for its own sake.

Comment: What are you trying to do specifically?  To my knowledge, there is no way to run an adb command directly, but you may be able to accomplish whatever you wanting to do another way.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is add a functionality(say a UI through a plugin) to eclipse which will make sure that end users don't need rely on adb commands for getting started with their work, for pulling and pushing some drivers to the android device, they will just use this eclipse UI instead which would be more user friendly. Let me know the other ways to do it.

Comment: Also my assumption that this may be possible was mainly based, on the fact that in built android SDK with eclipse already has an ADT plug in to launch android SDK manager or create an android virtual device(AVD's)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you could install a shell plugin, to give you access from within Eclipse, perhaps http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/easyshell

Or even better, you can execute some Shell commands directly from the console.  Looks like this SO question addresses exactly how to do that (and best of all, it is built in already).
[Is there an Eclipse plugin to run system shell in the Console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1562600/is-there-an-eclipse-plugin-to-run-system-shell-in-the-console)

This would allow you to execute any adb commands, as you would essentially be escaping to the shell anyway.

Comment: hmm, I still don't think this is what I'm trying to achieve. I don't need another console, may it be inside eclipse or outside. What I want to write is a UI which works according to my specific need but abstracts away the command line details from the end user. Now I can still explore on how to do that, but I was looking for an existing example which does this for its specific need,through its UI and abstracts away the details of command line for its own sake.