# Run ATG application in Eclipse

Tags: atg, atg-dynamo, atg-droplet

I was able to create an ATG project under Eclipse (using the wizard New ATG Application Moduke) but now I am not being able to run it on browser. 
When I right-click on index.jsp file I have no option to "Run on server".
What I am missing or doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: What application server are you using?

Comment: JBoss server, @Patrick. Do you know how I can do it?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if it possible because when you want to build and deploy ATG application you need to run assembling process that is defined in ATG tool ([doc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23507_01/Platform.20073/ATGMerchandisingUserGuide/html/s0305assemblinganddeployingapplicatio01.html)). Probably you can only run ant/maven task that will do the deployment nothing more.

Other option is to use [JRebel](http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/) which can update you java classes and jsp files on the fly without restarting the server.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a bat or shell script which run your app, you can apply approach from there https://stackoverflow.com/a/18729743/5049232