# Customize theme colors of eclipse TM terminal plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Is it possible to change the TM terminal color theme? https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/tm-terminal#group-details

Answer (score 19):

If you want black background color:

1. Go to Window / Preferences
2. Click on "Terminal"
3. Check the box "Invert terminal colors"
4. Click "Apply"

Comment: In other words: There is no way to change the color theme of the terminal in eclipse.

Comment: Above black ground color not applied because of  not using the color themes.

Comment: For me it does not work from the first time, I have to uncheck the box, apply, then check the box back, apply again, then restart eclipse and it works then.

Comment: There is now a way to change the colors - see my answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I implemented in the 2020-09 release (version 10.0) the ability to change the color themes, along with a number of other new features. Have a look at the [New and Noteworthy entry](https://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/NewIn100#Terminal)

The primary purpose was to be able to change individual colors because invert terminal often is insufficient to make everything visible.

Here is a screenshot of the new preference page:

[image: screenshot of preferences -> terminal to change colors]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this method didn't work for me. I wonder altho Eclipse kindly provided this option to "customomize", but it actually worked.

from your post and the asker's post, it seems like termimal is basically pretty useless.

In my case, I can check the maven version and run maven commands from regular system terminal, but eclipse terminal says Maven was not installed.

Comment: It's not an answer.