# How do i execute a shell script in eclipseIDE?

Tags: java, eclipse, shell

i want to execute a sheel on my Eclipse, and am unable to do so, is it because eclipse does not support shell script or do we any plugin for it.

I am executing it like this, and **Name** is Argument than i am passing to my script as search pattern.

```
$ String[] commands = {"C:/Users/shreyas.a.ramesh.DIR/workspace/Shellweb/src/Search_file.sh", Name};
```

And error I get is as follows

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program 
"C:/Users/shreyas.a.ramesh.DIR/workspace/Shellweb/src/Search_file.sh":   CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

Sorry about the code indentation.

Comment: Did you work on Linux or Windows?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an Eclipse plugin to run system shell in the Console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1562600/is-there-an-eclipse-plugin-to-run-system-shell-in-the-console)

Comment: It looks like you want to execute a shell script (`*.sh`) on Windows: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26522789/6505250

Comment: @howlger he want to use java, i think!

Comment: @PriyankaW it's not the same thing... He want to write in java programmatically the command...

Comment: @PriyankaW I am actually trying to execute my shell script from java, where and argument is passed from Java to my script as an input for a Search function

Comment: @Calaf yes i am using java.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a Java or Eclipse problem. Shell scripts aren't executable binaries. You'll have to run the shell binary itself with whatever arguments it needs to interpret your script.