# Show System.out.println output with another color

Tags: java, eclipse, colors, println

I have a big project to debug, and I was wondering if there is anyway I could use to change the `System.out.println` method in the output of eclipse

for example :

```
System.out.println("I want this to be red");
System.out.println("I want this to be blue");
System.out.println("I want this to be yellow");
System.out.println("I want this to be magenta");
```

for more readability.

`EDIT`

with sysout I have this
[image: sysout]

with syserr I have this
[image: syserr]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to print color in console using System.out.println?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762491/how-to-print-color-in-console-using-system-out-println)

Comment: most of the methods reported here work at the system console but NOT at the Eclipse console which is what the question was.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Within Eclipse, the simplest approach would be to use `System.err.println` for lines you want to be in red - I believe that's the default. (You can change it in Preferences -> Run/Debug -> Console).

That difference won't show up when running in a *real* console of course, but I don't *think* the Eclipse console supports ANSI colour escape sequences etc.

EDIT: For the Windows console, I'd expect [ANSI escape sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) to work. It's not *hugely* portable, but if that's not a problem, you could just create a class to encapsulate the escape sequences appropriately, so you could call something like:

```
ansiConsole.printRed("sample line in red");
ansiConsole.printBlue("sample line in blue");
```

(I'd probably make those methods return back to whatever the "current" colour was after each call.)

EDIT: As noted in comments, the [Jansi](http://jansi.fusesource.org/) library already exists, so you might as well use that. It doesn't have the methods described above, but I'm sure it'll still do what you want...

Comment: @OpenMind: Yes, but in a totally different way. What do you mean by "I don't have the same result" before?

Comment: @OpenMind: Try flushing after each write - I suspect it's a buffering issue.

Comment: Not working, I also tried your Jansi library. There no method called printRed() !

Comment: @OpenMind: "my" Jansi library? I don't have any library for ANSI escape sequences - I was suggesting that you wrote one yourself: "you could just create a class"...

Comment: (Having said which, it sounds like Jansi already has the functionality you want - just not encapsulated as I described. Will edit a reference into the answer.)

Comment: For Elipse Luna and MacOS 10.10, the only thing that worked for me is this: http://mihai-nita.net/2013/06/03/eclipse-plugin-ansi-in-console/

Answer (score 13):

Please Refer the following code.Also refer this link for ANSI color codes.          http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code

```
public class ColourConsoleDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        System.out.println("\033[0m BLACK");
        System.out.println("\033[31m RED");
        System.out.println("\033[32m GREEN");
        System.out.println("\033[33m YELLOW");
        System.out.println("\033[34m BLUE");
        System.out.println("\033[35m MAGENTA");
        System.out.println("\033[36m CYAN");
        System.out.println("\033[37m WHITE");
    }   
}
```

Comment: actually `\033[0m` stands for reset.

Comment: Brilliant!  I think this should be the accepted answer

Comment: i don't get the colour, only "?[32mSome test text?[0m" displayed in my eclipse console

Comment: > They want to print colored text in the Eclipse Console, not the Windows Command Prompt or terminal. Eclipse Console is not an ansi compatible console.  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51413044/how-to-print-colored-text-eclipse-photon/51414579#comment89798151_51413098

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look at [Jansi](http://jansi.fusesource.org/) ([Jansi's Github](https://github.com/fusesource/jansi))

> Jansi is a small java library that allows you to use ANSI escape
>   sequences to format your console output which works even on windows.

Comment: U can use this: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjansi14jar.htm if you want to use a jar instead of the archive. This resolved my import problem in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to highlight the output of `System.out.println()` using different colours in order to help you to debug , why don't redirect all the output of `System.out` to a file in your program entry point :

```
FileOutputStream fis = new FileOutputStream(new File("log.txt"));
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(fis); 
System.setOut(out);
```

Then using some free and portable real-time log file monitoring tool that has configurable highlighting function using different colours , such as  [BareTail](http://www.baremetalsoft.com/baretail/)  , to view this file.