# Is there a way i can change the print out color of my Text?

Tags: java, webdriver

> For Example

```
String text = "sample";
System.out.println(text);
```

> I want the text to appear in color RED.Tried java.awt but a bit confusing for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show System.out.println output with another color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7091003/show-system-out-println-output-with-another-color)

Comment: Thanks for the link unfortunately, System.out.println("\033[31m RED"); did not work for me..... but System.err.println("sample"); worked. sample was printed out in Red color.

Comment: You can add ANSI color codes in most terminals:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762491/how-to-print-color-in-console-using-system-out-println](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762491/how-to-print-color-in-console-using-system-out-println)

Comment: That didn't work for me reasons i know not. but below is what i did.                      `public String changeTextColor(String text)
 {
  System.err.println(text);
  return text;  
 } log.log(changeTextColor(Adam)); ` This printed Adam out in red color.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case you are using eclipse... you can use

```
System.err.println("...");
```

This will print in red in the eclipse console.

Answer (score 1):

You can change ANSI default color.
Lets say you have 2 colors

```
String Green = "\u001B[32m";
String Defauld = "\u001B[0m";
```

One string ,
    String word="Hello World";

and a printing code

```
System.out.print(Green + word + Defauld + "the end .");
```

And it print in Green.I dont know if this works in every system.Works in my Linux

PS:I dont have access in a pc right now could you please try the following in windows??

```
String Green = "\x1b[31m;
String Defauld = "\x1b[0m";
```

Comment: ....Dont think this works on windows. ANSI wont work with eclipse. System.out.print(Green + word + Defauld + "the end ."); prints out :  "[32mword[0m the end".

Comment: Throws an error @ "\x     "invalid escape sequence"

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use JCDP (Java Colored Debug Printer) which works on both Windows and Linux. Response from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/6957561 .

GitHub: https://github.com/dialex/JCDP#downloads
I have just tried the example in IntelliJ on Windows 7 and here's the result:
[image]