# How to make numbers highlighted in Java?

Tags: java, calculator, highlighting

I am using BlueJ as my IDE for this school project...

This is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculator{ 

public static void main(String[]args){

System.out.println("Enter your first number here:");

        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

        double number1 = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println(""); //Skipping a line for a better organised presentation

        System.out.println("Enter the second number here");
        double number2 = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println(""); 

        double answer = number1 + number2;
        //code for highlighting the answer 
        System.out.println("The answer is:"+answer);

     }
}
```

I was working on this Calculator class then I thought about **highlighting the answer** to that it stands out more than the other numbers...

I've tried experimenting with JFrame before but it didn't quite work out for me...

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change text color in the JtextArea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650992/how-to-change-text-color-in-the-jtextarea)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print color in console using System.out.println?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762491/how-to-print-color-in-console-using-system-out-println)

Comment: Or if you want to stick to the console, you can use this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25683444/829571

Comment: The default console doesn't support any formatting at all. More advanced consoles exist but are difficult to get used to (they don't run in an IDE like BlueJ). A `JFrame` is your only easy-ish option.

Comment: GUI toolkits seem a little out of your reach at the moment and the console only supports colours on unix / cygwin. Honestly, I really wouldn't worry about making purely aesthetic changes like this at the moment.

Comment: @MarkJeronimus so if I try to use Eclipse to work out this project will those advanced consoles run?

Comment: @Benit afaik it doesn't work in any IDE.

Comment: @MarkJeronimus Thanks