# How to print colored text? [Eclipse Photon]

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to use System.out.println to print colored text. I am using the latest version of Java in Java Eclipse Photon. I've looked up other tutorials but none have helped. I do not want to use plugins but rather anything in the standard JDK. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can't do this, the Eclipse console does not support colors.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think Eclipse console supports colors declared from Java output. Please see http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fpreferences%2Frun-debug%2Fref-console.htm

The docs only show how to change the text color as a whole. However you can have different colors for standard out:

```
System.out.println("standard out");
```

vs Standard error

```
System.err.println("standard out");
```

The following is a solution for both Mac and Linux terminals:

Create the following class

```
public class ANSIConstants {
  public static final String ANSI_RESET = "\u001B[0m";
  public static final String ANSI_BLACK = "\u001B[30m";
  public static final String ANSI_RED = "\u001B[31m";
  public static final String ANSI_GREEN = "\u001B[32m";
  public static final String ANSI_YELLOW = "\u001B[33m";
  public static final String ANSI_BLUE = "\u001B[34m";
  public static final String ANSI_PURPLE = "\u001B[35m";
  public static final String ANSI_CYAN = "\u001B[36m";
  public static final String ANSI_WHITE = "\u001B[37m";
}
```

Then you can do the following

```
System.out.println(ANSIConstants.ANSI_PURPLE + "example" + ANSIConstants.ANSI_RESET);
```

Comment: Sorry, I can confirm it works in the linux terminal.

Comment: @JasonHeithoff I think we both misunderstood OP. They want to print colored text in the Eclipse Console, not the Windows Command Prompt or terminal. Eclipse Console is not an ansi compatible console.

Answer (score 2):

In eclipse(Neon) Go to Windows > Preferences  then search for **Run/Debug** after that click on **Console** under the **Run/Debug**. There are four option available for changing the console view:

1. Standard out color
2. Standard error color
3. Console Background
4. Standard In color

See the image for more detail (I think this setting is also work in Photon) [image]