# Changing color of output in Java eclipse code

Tags: java

```
System.out.println("Path : "+ d.get("path") +", Contents : " + d.get("contents") + ", Score : " + sd.score);
```

I want to highlight my output, especially the score part. How do I do that in Java so that I can highlight my scores? The content is huge and reader can't read score easily.

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7091003/show-system-out-println-output-with-another-color

Comment: The Eclipse console doesn't support colours.

Comment: There are plugins like [this](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/ansi-escape-console) coloring ANSI escape codes in the eclipse console.