# How to print highlighted color text in console using System.out.println in Java

Tags: java, printing, colors, console

How can I print a text on console with highlighted colour.

I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762491/how-to-print-color-in-console-using-system-out-println) but this talks about printing text in colur and not highlighting it with another color.

Example:

[image]

Comment: How does printing in a colour, and highlighting in a colour differ ?

Comment: @Brian Agnew : I have edited my question to add an image to clear the difference between colored text and highlighted text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To switch on a yellow background (say), you need the escape sequence

```
java.lang.String("\033[43m");
```

Combine this with a black foreground to get what you want.

I'm getting the escape sequences from [this Scala doc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Console%24.html). Although it's Scala doc it's relevant and applicable in Java. The [Jansi](http://jansi.fusesource.org/documentation/api/index.html) library should handle this. See the 'background' references in the `Ansi` class.