# Colors for TEXT in java

Tags: java

I want to know if there is any function or something so can change my text color
like: System.out.println("hi")
the text "hi" will be in red 
and same as others texts
thk

Comment: Not without using some sort of GUI. Just plain printing does not involve colors.

Comment: If you happen to be using an IDE like Eclipse, and you specifically want red... `System.err.println("hi")`.

Comment: @RussellZahniser That's a bad idea... printing to the error stream should only be done if there is an *error*.

Comment: @arshajii do you think OP wants to write a serious programm? ... i would say in this case it's ok

Comment: @PhilippSander I disagree; we should instill best practices from an early stage.

Comment: System.err.println has nothing to do with red...It prints to a totally different output stream, and the IDE happens to print that stream in red.  It's a behavior of the environment, not the language.

Comment: Possible duplicate:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762491/how-to-print-color-in-console-using-system-out-println

Comment: Use System.err.println and don't listen @arshajii

Comment: @hellzone Making an unsubstantiated claim like that doesn't mean much. In any case, it's a terrible idea for a variety of reasons. As Ian McLaird rightfully pointed out, it's not guaranteed to work everywhere. Moreover, it's just a bad practice to print to the error stream arbitrarily, as I mentioned in a comment to a since-deleted answer below.

Comment: Why would you assume that he's *not* writing a serious program?  It's clearly serious enough that he wants to provide color-coded output.  This is a serious question, with a somewhat tricky real answer (see the other question I linked to).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no, because `System.out` uses plain standard system output.

If you would like to color some text, then use some GUI, using for example `Swing`.

Comment: If the terminal you're running on supports ANSI escape sequences, you have more options:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762491/how-to-print-color-in-console-using-system-out-println