# Java - How to use ANSI in java

Tags: java, colors, ansi-escape, jansi

I am trying to send coloured messages in the console with ANSI. I added the jasni 1.9 to my jar and I tried to use the methods of ansi but that did not work. 
The second thing I have tried was to go to the jansi website but the website was down. 
And the third thing I tried was to go to youtube and google but I could not find any tutorials to install jansi.
What happens when I add it to my build path and try 1 of the methods it say that I could not find the method.
What did I do wrong or how do I install it else?

Comment: have you seen these links? https://code.google.com/p/jlibs/wiki/AnsiColoring and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762491/how-to-print-color-in-console-using-system-out-println

Comment: 'Did not work' is not a problem description. Neither is 'could not find the method'. No code provided. 'Website was down' isn't relevant to questions here. Unanwerable as is.

Comment: @RafaelOsipov yes i did but it does not recoginze Ansi ansi = new Ansi ansi = new Ansi(Ansi.Attribute.BRIGHT, Ansi.Color.BLUE, Ansi.Color.WHITE);