# printing colored strings in java in windows

Tags: java, string

i was trying to print colored string in bluej using

```
public static final String ANSI_RESET = "\u001B[0m";
public static final String ANSI_BLACK = "\u001B[30m";
public static final String ANSI_RED = "\u001B[31m";
public static final String ANSI_GREEN = "\u001B[32m";
public static final String ANSI_YELLOW = "\u001B[33m";
public static final String ANSI_BLUE = "\u001B[34m";
public static final String ANSI_PURPLE = "\u001B[35m";
public static final String ANSI_CYAN = "\u001B[36m";
public static final String ANSI_WHITE = "\u001B[37m";
```

but i was not getting the desired result
please help me get colored easily

Comment: how you try to print colored text?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print color in console using System.out.println?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762491/how-to-print-color-in-console-using-system-out-println)

Comment: Please write more specific what you have tried and what is your goal?!

Comment: i have tried to print    System.out.println(ANSI_RED+"Bang Bang"+RESET); I want to print bang bang in red.

Comment: I have windows 7.May be it was important

Answer (score 0):

Windows does not have the necessary ANSI color library that is needed to print colored text...You may have to search for an ANSI library.

My System runs XUBUNTU and the color code works perfectly.

Therefore the problem is with Windows.