# How to print the exception in different color

Tags: java, exception

Is there any way in java to print the entire exception message (including all stack-trace) in different color (for example in red) . The reason being, i would like to showcase the fatal error/exception in some different way. If the exception message also prints in same way as the general log prints , then it's difficult to trace the actual exception compare to log.

Please suggest on how to do that.
Is there any different way , then please suggest

Regards

Comment: I assume all the log messages go into a log file, and then you tail/grep the log. Is that the case? If it is, then depending on your text editor of choice, you can create a syntax file that would do the highlighting. I use vim, and I created a syntax file just for the purpose of highlighting tomcat logs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print color in console using System.out.println?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762491/how-to-print-color-in-console-using-system-out-println)

Comment: You may simply redirect exception/error logs to different output stream.

Answer (score 2):

The recommended practice is to print error messages to `System.err`, and normal output to `System.out`.
Modern terminal applications are usually configured to display text coming from `stderr` in red color, distinguishing from normal output.

If that is not good enough for you (but I hope it is),
then another alternative as suggested by @Siguza is to use ANSI colors, as demonstrated in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762491/how-to-print-color-in-console-using-system-out-println).

Comment: [ANSI colors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors) are a thing though...

Answer (score 0):

For consoles that don't automatically print stderr in red, you can make a java class that extends output stream to add the ANSI color codes. Making a seperate output stream class and then setting the output with `System.setErr(new PrintStream(new ColoredOutputStream(System.err)))` makes it so that even if you call something like e.printStackTrace it will still be red. for example this is what I use:

```
    public class ColoredOutputStream extends OutputStream 
    {
        OutputStream errStream;
        red = "\033[31m";
        reset = "\033[0m";   
        public ColoredErrorStream(OutputStream outputStream){
            errStream = outputStream;
        }
            @Override
        public void write(int b) throws IOException
        {
            errStream.write(red.getBytes());
            errStream.write(b);     
            errStream.write(reset.getBytes());
        }
        
        @Override
        public void write(byte[] b) throws IOException
        {
            errStream.write(red.getBytes());
            errStream.write(b);
            errStream.write(reset.getBytes());
        }
    
        @Override
        public void write(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException
        {
            errStream.write(red.getBytes());
            errStream.write(b, off, len);
            errStream.write(reset.getBytes());
                
        }
    
        @Override
        public void flush() throws IOException
        {
                errStream.flush();
        }
    
        @Override
        public void close() throws IOException
        {
                errStream.close();
        }
    }
```