# Making text more attractive in java

Tags: java

How can I use some font and color property to show this more attractive..Any opinion highly appreciated and i am printing this in simple "System.out.println"

```
Net Salary : 13888.0
Account Number : 1011121313
EmpID : 106
Basic Salary : 800.0
PFA : 12.0 %
Taxes : 2.0 %
Email : roopam@gmail.com
Bonus : 2000
Total Working Days : 20
Total Leaves : 5
```

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762491/how-to-print-color-in-console-using-system-out-println

Comment: JLine2 is a neat library for this kind of stuff https://github.com/jline/jline2/blob/master/src/test/java/jline/example/Example.java

Answer (score 1):

**println** used to print **line**(or **lines**) of String in terminal(command line) , so i think there is no option for printing with font and color

if you wanna customize your text , you can use java swing to have a graphical environment , and use jLabel , jTextField , ... for making beautiful texts