# Difference between ANSI color?

Tags: ansi-colors

I was searching about changing output color for console in NetBeans and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762491/how-to-print-color-in-console-using-system-out-println) post. 
I tried the first answer and worked perfectly for changing colors. I tried the fifth answer and... worked too.

My question is: why the strings designated for every color are different in first and fifth?

First answer's example:

```
public static final String ANSI_BLUE = "\u001B[34m";
```

Fifth answer's example:

```
public static final String BLUE = "\033[0;34m";    // BLUE
```

I made a little research but I really couldn't figure why.

I appreciate an answer or help in pointing me to understand it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The backslash notation denotes one byte local representation octal numbers. The `\u` notation denotes 16 bit hexadecimal Unicode representation. Both `\u001b` and `\033` denote an ESC, so they are the same in that regard.

With that said, the two sequences are not the same. The first sequence gives one command, `34`, which means "foreground color blue". The second sequence gives two commands, separated by a semicolon. The second one is `34`, but the first one is `0`, which means "Reset".

So the first sequence changes color to blue, while the second one resets the settings and then sets the color to blue.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the given answer, I would like to add a bit of information I found in [this] [1](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php) link. In the page you can see the different ways to construct an escape sequence and the meaning of every part of it, as well as possible values. As an example:

> `Esc[Value;...;Valuem`
> **Set Graphics Mode:**
> Calls the graphics functions specified by the following values. These specified functions remain active until the next occurrence of this escape sequence. Graphics mode changes the colors and attributes of text (such as bold and underline) displayed on the screen.

> **Text attributes**
> 0   All attributes off
> 1   Bold on
> 4   Underscore (on monochrome display adapter only)
> 5   Blink on
> 7   Reverse video on
> 8   Concealed on

Update: the link provided above seems to be down, but the page is still available in http://web.archive.org/, the last snapshot was http://web.archive.org/web/20210226122732/http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php