# Simple Steps on How to Change Colors in Java Eclipse Console

Tags: java, eclipse, colors

How do you change the colors of Eclipse console using code? I know for red you can use System.err.print("test"); but I want a generalization for any color.

For example, I want a line of one color being blue, another line being magenta, and so on.

Comment: Eclipse Preferences > General > Appearance?

Comment: Do you mean you want to be able to write a program that prints multi-coloured text in the console (which can't be done, by the way); or do you just mean that you want to change the default black, red and green of the console to something different (which is easy)?

Comment: I see.  Your edit answers my question.  And what you want can't be done.  Sorry.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem _[...] And what you want can't be done_ [That's not entirely true](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5762502/1426227).

Comment: @CassioMazzochiMolin Feel free to post that as an answer, and I will downvote it.  OP asked about the standard Eclipse console, not some customised console.

Comment: This isn't really a duplicate since it's specific to Eclipse. I updated my answer with a link to a plugin that gives the Eclipse console support for color changing ANSI codes.

Comment: @CassioMazzochiMolin, I agree with Sean.  This isn't a duplicate.  Would you consider re-opening it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally you cannot change console colors using Java code.  Eclipse recognizes "System.err.print" as an error and displays a unique color for that, which is red by default.  You can change various defaults in the preferences, but again, there is no Java code that allows you to pick a console output color.

Per Cassio's comment, there are ANSI escape codes to change colors but the console must support it. In order to support it in Eclipse, this plugin is available. https://github.com/mihnita/ansi-econsole

Comment: _[...] there is no Java code that allows you to pick a console output color._ [That's not entirely true](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5762502/1426227).