# ESC not working in java when using cmd.exe

Tags: java

I am trying to color the output of my game.

It Works with Netbeans, but in cmd.exe just displays `<-`,
The code I am trying to color is

```java
System.out.print("/033[34m[GAME/info]: FPS recorder has start/033[0m");
        
System.out.print("\n/033[37m[GAME/debug]: FPS Print-Out will print every "+ time +".000ms/033[37m");
```

[Cmd image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcPU6.png)

[NetBeans image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjxZP.png)

Comment: Maybe these will help: [How to print escape character to Windows console from java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45081061/how-to-print-escape-character-to-windows-console-from-java) or [How can you use vt100 escape codes in java on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52767585/how-can-you-use-vt100-escape-codes-in-java-on-windows)

Comment: @Abra   Tried both, does not work still