# Java print escape characters from text file

Tags: java

I am having ANSI escape-sequences inline in code that works, but I cannot get it to work when reading the same string from at text file.

dOut.writeBytes("\033[0;31;1m> help (?)          - Get help\n");

(dOut = DataOutputStream)

This prints red text og black background.

When reading the exact same line from a text file it does not work, it prints the line as pure text.

```
                BufferedReader menuReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("help.txt"));
                while ((menuLine = menuReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    dOut.writeBytes(menuLine + "\n");
                }
                menuReader.close();
```

Text file has only one line: \033[0;31;1m> help (?) - Get help

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others. It should show how it generates the red text when used directly and how it generates only pure text when read from a file.

Comment: Do you have the text `"\033"` (4 characters) inside the file or do you have the byte 0x1B inside the file?

Comment: Thanks for answering, Progman :-) The text, not the byte. I do not know how to get 0x1B into the text...

Comment: With any hexeditor of your choice or via java with a `FileOutputStream`.

Comment: So, how do I get about to substitude the text "\033" (or whatever) with the byte 0x1B in code? I know how to replace substrings, but not bytes...

Comment: normal `replace()` call, where you replace `"\\033"` with `"\033"`, so you replace the 4 character long string with the 0x1B byte. Or you save the 0x1B byte inside the file so you don't need to replace the text when reading the file.

Comment: Ok, Progman, I will test this as soon as I'm back @ my machine, thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

Write a parser that recognizes particular patterns and convert them into desired string.

Answer (score 0):

The colouring syntax is usually specific to the shell being used e.g. one syntax might work in Bash Shell on Linux but will fail with Cygwin Bash Shell on Windows. Moreover some terminals might not print all the colours combinations e.g. black background with light grey text sometimes doesn't work.

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5762502/1602555) you have to use a unicode syntax. To get red text on white background use below:

```
String redFg = "\u001B[31m";
String blackBg = "\u001B[40m";
System.out.println(blackBg + redFg + "> help (?) - Get help");
```

In your file you are using `\033` which is an octal value equal to `\001B` hex. You would have to convert your formatting syntax to the one supported by Java.

Comment: Yes, thank you Karol. And that works fine when setting the colors in code, but I need to set the colors in the text file :-) I've updated the question with some more info.