# Making System.out.println(); Statements red in Java

Tags: java, colors

## How do I make this output "Make this a different color", but in red? In Java.

### Sorry for stupid question

`System.out.println("Make this  a different color");`

Comment: check this out :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762491/how-to-print-color-in-console-using-system-out-println

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
        System.out.println("\033[0;31m Make this  a different color");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't do it in Java if you are printing to the console.