# log4j.properties file not giving desired output

Tags: java, log4j

I have a java project in which i use log4j for logging i used appender to provide different color for different logs but it is printing all log levels in black
my log4j.properties

```
log4j.debug=false

# Default level is INFO
log4j.rootLogger=INFO,StdoutErrorFatal,StdoutWarn,StdoutInfo,StdoutDebug,StdoutTrace

# and for com.some.package.* log everything
log4j.logger.com.some.package=TRACE

log4j.appender.StdoutErrorFatal=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.StdoutErrorFatal.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.StdoutErrorFatal.layout.conversionPattern=\u001b[31;1m%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p - %-26c - 
[user:%X{username}] %m\n
log4j.appender.StdoutErrorFatal.threshold=ERROR

log4j.appender.StdoutWarn=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.StdoutWarn.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.StdoutWarn.layout.conversionPattern=\u001b[33;1m%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p - %-26c - 
 [user:%X{username}] %m\n
 log4j.appender.StdoutWarn.threshold=WARN
 log4j.appender.StdoutWarn.filter.filter1=org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter
 log4j.appender.StdoutWarn.filter.filter1.levelMin=WARN
 log4j.appender.StdoutWarn.filter.filter1.levelMax=WARN

  log4j.appender.StdoutInfo=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
  log4j.appender.StdoutInfo.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
  log4j.appender.StdoutInfo.layout.conversionPattern=\u001b[0m%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p - %-26c - [user:%X{username}] %m\n
  log4j.appender.StdoutInfo.threshold=INFO
  log4j.appender.StdoutInfo.filter.filter1=org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter
  log4j.appender.StdoutInfo.filter.filter1.levelMin=INFO
   log4j.appender.StdoutInfo.filter.filter1.levelMax=INFO

   log4j.appender.StdoutDebug=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
   log4j.appender.StdoutDebug.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
   log4j.appender.StdoutDebug.layout.conversionPattern=\u001b[0;36m%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p - %-26c - [user:%X{username}] %m\n
   log4j.appender.StdoutDebug.threshold=DEBUG        
 log4j.appender.StdoutDebug.filter.filter1=org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter
 log4j.appender.StdoutDebug.filter.filter1.levelMin=DEBUG
 log4j.appender.StdoutDebug.filter.filter1.levelMax=DEBUG
```

i have given 31 for red foreground in error log but my error shows up black
screenshot of my output
[image: my output]

here the underlined line is a error log which i expect to come in red color but its showing black

code i give error

```
   if (Files.exists(des)) {
      logger.info("Reports Generated in "+userHomePath+"/Reports");
     
    }
 else{
    logger.error("Please ensure the source files are located in "+userHomePath);
 }
```

Comment: Does your console support colorization?

Comment: You can test with this approach https://stackoverflow.com/a/5762502/8343843