# Print strings on terminal with color

Tags: java, terminal

Can anyone tell me how to print my strings on terminal with color in Java? If there is a library for that purpose please introduce it to me, I rather use one than do the job myself:)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print color in console using System.out.println?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762491/how-to-print-color-in-console-using-system-out-println)

Comment: @AlexandruSomai Thank you yes this is the answer of my question but I rather to use the lib that [Soroush Shemshadi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69971248/17415929) provides. Although I found another library for this purpose in answers of question you referenced. I must check both to see which one is better. Thanks anyway:)

Answer (score 0):

The console output screen is black or white by default.

If you want to Highlight some text on the output screen, you can use the ANSI color codes and highlight the particular text.

```
System.out.println(ANSI_COLORNAME + "This text is colored" + ANSI_RESET);
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes there is. I've implemented a library named [JTerminal](https://github.com/shuoros/JTerminal) in Java to print custom outputs on terminal, Including print and println with your desired foreground and background colors. It supports 8-bit 256 colors(XTerm code).

It's an easy to use library. To print your string with color you want, You just need to make a static call to `print` or `println` method:

```java
import io.github.shuoros.jterminal.JTerminal;
import io.github.shuoros.jterminal.ansi.Color;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Prints "Hello World!" with orange foreground color
        JTerminal.println("Hello World!", Color.ORANGE);
        // Prints "Hello World!" with orange foreground and white background color
        JTerminal.println("Hello World!", Color.ORANGE, Color.WHITE);
    }
}
```

You can also colorize your string with different colors in different ranges by one line of code:

```java
import java.util.List;

import io.github.shuoros.jterminal.JTerminal;
import io.github.shuoros.jterminal.ansi.Color;
import io.github.shuoros.jterminal.util.TextEntity;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Prints ">JTerminal:~ 1.0.2" with the colors of its logo
        JTerminal.println(">JTerminal:~ 1.0.2", List.of(//
                new TextEntity(0, 1, Color.DARK_SEA_GREEN_7), //
                new TextEntity(1, 10, Color.ORANGE), //
                new TextEntity(10, 12, Color.DARK_SEA_GREEN_7), //
                new TextEntity(12, 18, Color.WHITE)));
    }
}
```

To add [JTerminal](https://github.com/shuoros/JTerminal) to your maven or gradle project you can add its dependecy:

#### Maven

```xml
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.shuoros/JTerminal -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.shuoros</groupId>
    <artifactId>JTerminal</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

#### Gradle

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.shuoros/JTerminal
implementation group: 'io.github.shuoros', name: 'JTerminal', version: '1.0.2'
```

Head over to [JTerminal github repository](https://github.com/shuoros/JTerminal) for some examples.

Comment: Well, Thank you very much, But how can I find out which colors your library supports?

Comment: @MaximFedorov As I mentioned in answer, JTerminal supports 8-bit 256 colors. to see all of the supported colors please read [color docs](https://github.com/shuoros/JTerminal/tree/main/doc/Colors)